# How to convert DateTime.Now to this format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am unable to understand how to convert `DateTime.Now` to some format such as `2015-06-04T14:13:00`

What does `T` here represent and how to convert it to this format?

Comment: what you  have tried

Comment: I tried DateTime.Now.ToString(), ToFileTime(), ToLongDateString(), ToLongTimeString(). None of which gave me this format.

Comment: Look up `ToString()` on MSDN, you can provide custom format specificers - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It's an ISO 8601 standard date.

Answer (score 4):

I'm *really* taking risk to answer that but..

You can escape the `T` character with single quotes and use a culture that have `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (eg: [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) like;

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As a better way, you can use [The `"s"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Sortable) which represents in [`SortableDateTimePattern` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.sortabledatetimepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"` custom string which is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("s"); // 2015-06-22T15:17:27
```

What is `T` for exactly?

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

> A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete
>   date expression, the letter `T` as a delimiter, and a valid time
>   expression. For example `"2007-04-05T14:30"`.
>
> If a time zone designator is required, it follows the combined date
>   and time. For example `"2007-04-05T14:30Z"` or `"2007-04-05T12:30-02:00"`.
>
> Either basic or extended formats may be used, but both date and time
>   must use the same format. The date expression may be calendar, week,
>   or ordinal, and must use a complete representation. The time
>   expression may use reduced accuracy. It is permitted to omit the `'T'`
>   character by mutual agreement.

and

> By mutual agreement of the partners in information interchange, the
>   character `[T]` may be omitted in applications where there is no risk
>   of confusing a date and time of day representation with others defined
>   in this International Standard.

Comment: Risk for what. Not to worry it is totally a valid question even though trollers gave me 7 negatives. Let them be happy haha. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Jack It's a poor question with next to no effort from you, so he's running the risk of *spoon feeding* you vs. actually helping.

Comment: You can also just parse it to a `DateTimeOffset`, then use the `DateTime` property on that: `var date = DateTimeOffset.Parse(item).DateTime`

Comment: @mattytommo I don't think this is relevant. `DateTimeOffset` doesn't seems an issue here. OP just want to get a special repreresentation of a `DateTime` which fits with ISO 8601 format. Even if there is no standard date and time format for his result, he can use custom date and time strings.

Comment: @SonerGönül I know, but using `DateTimeOffset` is arguably easier than having to specify the format that we already know is ISO 8601, no need to specify the format as it's not a custom one per-se

Comment: @mattytommo Hmm, sounds reasonable..